# unable to increase code coverage for getter and setter methods in test class

Tags: unit-test

I am unable to increase code coverage for getter and setter methods in test class. Please some one suggest how to increase code coverage for it.

I am having code:

```
get{
    lstAcct = [select Id,name from Account Limit :recordLimit OFFSET :offSetLimit ];
    return lstAcct;
}set;
     }
```

for this code it is showing in red color and pls some one help me out for increasing code coverage.

Comment: can you post your code here?

Answer (score 0):

In your test method add:

```
Account[] a = CONTROLLERNAME.PROPERTYNAME;
system.assertEquals(false,a.isEmpty()); //Or whatever it should be
```